# SQL Join tables (multiple number of id's)

Tags: sql

I have two tables:
The first one (players) contains player records with it ID's and names.
Another one (results) contains results:
ID of 1 player against ID of 2 player
How can I select their names?

```
SELECT *
FROM results
ORDER by result_date DESC
```

It looks like this for now. I want to have instead of numbers real player names.

[image]

Comment: Are you storing both player ids in the same column?  If so, that's not the best way to store this data as it's going to make it incredibly difficult to query it.

Answer (score 0):

This could help:

```
SELECT players.ID, players.Name
FROM players
INNER JOIN results ON players.ID=results.playersID
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set two different alias for the players table:

```
select *
from results 
     join players as pair1players on results.Pair1 = pair1players.ID
     join players as pair2players on results.Pair2 = pair2players.ID
order by result_date desc
```

Here, supposing Pair1 is the name of the field "Pair #1" you showed in the screenshot, and Pair2 is the name of the field "Pair #2".